# How to scale UILabel text to fit the label

Tags: ios, swift

I'm teaching myself swift by trying to build a calendar that's similar in design to the apple calendar. I've hit a small snag though. On apple's calendar, if you make an event that's too small for the title to fit on the event, it shrinks the text.

how do I do that on a UILabel (in swift)?... on my app the text just doesn't show up

thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for UILabel? Look at `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Depends on how much you want to let it scale down by, but if you want to let it go down to half its size, you can do it either in the XIB/storyboard or you can do it manually by code:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

If you're desperate you can get the label to tighten the character spacing using:

```
label.allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = true
```